# How to make dynamic PHP class

Tags: php

I have a class Config. Whenever `'localhost'` is in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, I want the $db_host to be `'localhost'`. By default it should be `'defaulthost'`;

```
class Config {

    public static $db_username = 'username';
    public static $db_password = 'password';
    public static $db_database = 'database';

    public function __construct() {
        $host = 'defaulthost';
    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'localhost')){
        $host = 'localhost';
    };
        self::$db_host = $host;
    }
 }
```

This code is giving me an error

Comment: so... `public static $db_host;` should fix that up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare property $db_host.

```
class Config {
    public static $db_username = 'username';
    public static $db_password = 'password';
    public static $db_database = 'database';
    public static $db_host = 'defaulthost';

    public function __construct() {
        if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost')){
            self::$db_host = 'localhost';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize db_host in same way like you did with db_database ;-)